# Inject script into iframe inside Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that contains a page, chrome-extension://foo/index.html

That page contains an iframe, which loads pages I do not own (not on the same domain).

I want to inject a script into that iframe from the Chrome extension - however, URLs starting with chrome-extension:// are not a valid match pattern for either the "permissions" or "content_scripts" field of the manifest (so I cannot inject it programmatically or declaratively). I am able to inject the script if I host my index.html file elsewhere (not as part of the Chrome extension), but it's annoying to have to have part of my Chrome extension hosted elsewhere. Is there any way to give my extension permissions to inject a script in an iframe inside a file that it owns?

Comment: No, but you can add something like `?param123=456` with random digits to the URL of the iframe and use the same in your `content_scripts` declaration in manifest.json for `matches`, as well as `"all_frames": true` of course.

Comment: Thanks, this will help with the matching, but not the permissions, I think? I have <all_urls> included in the permissions, but injecting into any frame on a chrome-extension:// page seems to fail because the parent is chrome-extension://. Were you able to get around that?

Comment: No, you will declare it in manifest.json, you won't use executeScript.

Comment: Thanks - I don't think this will work for me, because it won't inject the script when the user loads a new page into the iframe - injecting from the manifest only works on the initial parent page load. I need to inject the script into every page loaded in the iframe (so I need a listener on the iframe's load event so I can call executeScript).

Comment: You can use chrome.webRequest or chrome.webNavigation to intercept navigation in the iframe and add that parameter.

Comment: Yes, but it still won't trigger injection via "matches" - as far as I can tell, Chrome extensions only check whether to inject into a page when the top level frame does a hard nav.

Comment: It will. Frame navigation is handled just the same, assuming you specified `all_frames`, see above.

Comment: That worked! Weird, I could've sworn I tried something very similar earlier - but this works great, thank you!

Comment: Mind if I ask how you were able to intercept the navigation to add the parameter? (Specifically, which of the events did you listen to? onBeforeNavigate?) If you have a code snippet handy, that would be super helpful, but if not no worries!

Comment: Use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest (with `types: ['sub_frame']`) or even the new chrome.declarativeNetRequest.